# Timespan go wrong

Tags: vb.net, time, timer, counter, timespan

I want to add a label that prints the elapsed time like a normal clock (when seconds reachs "59" then add "1" min to the counter) but my time span add minutes when the seconds reaches the number "30"... what I'm doing wrong?

```
    Dim ElapsedTime As TimeSpan

 While log_button.Text = "Stop logger"
            ElapsedTime = Now().Subtract(StartTime)
            Label5.Text = String.Format("Minutos transcurridos: {0:00}:{1:00}", CInt(ElapsedTime.TotalMinutes) Mod 60, CInt(ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds) Mod 60)
            Application.DoEvents()
 End While
```

I get a wrong incrementation like this:

[image]

[image]

00:01

...

00:28

00:29

00:30

01:31

01:32

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are rounding the floating point number that represents total minutes. When the numbers reaches `0.5` it will be rounded to 1.

Use the `Floor` method to truncate the number:

```
CInt(Math.Floor(ElapsedTime.TotalMinutes)) Mod 60
```

You can also use the `Minutes` property, that does all that:

```
ElapsedTime.Minutes
```